# df.dropna() not working and still appear in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to clean my dataset and for some reason the Nan's and "#N/A Invalid security" still show up. I tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\rgoldstein27\Desktop\1-M index bond drivers.xlsx')
df.dropna(how='any')
df['EBITDA_TO_TOT_INT_EXP'] = pd.to_numeric(df['EBITDA_TO_TOT_INT_EXP'],errors='coerce')
df.sort_values(by=['EBITDA_TO_TOT_INT_EXP'])
```

And they are still there. Im not sure why this is the case.

Comment: We need a [Minimal Compete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your data. Without it, noone can understand what "they are still there" means. I think you mean you have **string** "NaN" and "#N/A Invalid security" in your data (not `pd.np.nan`), and you're expecting that `dropna()` should figure out their meaning is equivalent to `nan` and replace them. But it won't.

Comment: ...or you might mean that you expect `dropna()` should operate with `inplace=True` by default, but it doesn't. Or maybe both of the above. Which is it? Without seeing your data we can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: How can i tell if the value is a string? in the file, the data does have "#N/A N/A" as a return and when i look at the table the value is "NaN" and "#N/A Invalid Security"

- how can i tell if this is a string?

Comment: There's a huge difference between `nan` and 'NaN'. The latter is a string, not an actual nan value. (Also `df.info()` will tell you if that column is string ("object") or numeric).

Comment: In the excel file i am importing -  "#N/A N/A" and  "#N/A Invalid Security" are in cells
In the Jupyter notebook i am using, there is a table that shows "NaN" and ""#N/A Invalid Security" as returns. Both stay in the table when i use df.dropna()

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3756 entries, 0 to 3755
Data columns (total 13 columns):
ID                                 1878 non-null object
ID_BB_GLOBAL                       1878 non-null object
DEBT_TO_EQUITY_FUNDAMENTALS_TKR    3499 non-null object
CLASSIFICATION_LEVEL_4_NAME        3711 non-null object
INDEX_YIELD_TO_WORST               1878 non-null float64
INDEX_TOTAL_RETURN_MTD             1878 non-null float64
INDEX_EXCESS_RETURN_MTD            3756 non-null object
NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA                 3497 non-null object

Comment: EV_EBIT_ADJUSTED                   1475 non-null object
TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY                3505 non-null object
EBITDA_TO_TOT_INT_EXP              3175 non-null float64
CHG_PCT_1M                         1588 non-null object
INDEX_OAS_TSY                      3756 non-null object
dtypes: float64(3), object(10)
memory usage: 381.5+ KB

Comment: Also, if you want to replace nan values with some other value, use `df.fillna()` not `dropna()`, which only drops rows containing NaNs. You have to **tell us specifically what you expect your output to be: "they are still there" is really unclear: did you mean a) you want the NA values to be replaced (with what value?) and the rows kept? or b) you want those rows to be dropped?**

Comment: I want to remove all the rows that have any column returns of "NaN" or "#N/A Invalid Security"

Answer (score 1):

`df.dropna()` creates a new copy, doesn't modify in place, by default. If you want inplace, you should set `inplace=True`:

```
DataFrame.dropna(self, axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

Comment: This is not the OP's issue. Their issue is that they think `dropna()` drops any string value that resembles "N/A" - which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify inplace=True to df.dropna statement like this:
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)